# Error in probes within Azure gateway shared with other services using AGIC

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

For some days I have been facing a somewhat thorny mistake.

I have a k8s cluster exposed on a gateway that I share with other applications.
On the k8s side we have installed AGIC to expose the cluster, in the Application Gateway there is a httpplistener that I have included in the AzureIngressProhibitedTarget.

The problems started when I added a new listener to the Application Gateway, creating a new AzureIngressProhibitedTarget.

The problem is that every time we deploy any microservice hosted in the cluster we get stuck with a 502 error when we try to access the application.

Analyzing the problem we first found an error like this:

```
reason: FailedApplyingAppGwConfig
message: >-
  network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
  StatusCode=0 -- Original Error:
  Code="ApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRulePartialPriorityDefined"
  Message="Either all or no rule should have the priority specified." Details=[]
source:
  component: azure/application-gateway
  host: application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress-ingress-azure-74f75pb2dl
```

Unable to find the problem, we deleted and recreated the listener and everything started working again.

Today I did a new deployment and I ran into the same error (502 when I try to access the application), analyzing the problem I found the following errors in the pod events of a service that had not been modified for a long time:

```
message: >-
  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://[ip]:15902/osm-readiness-probe":
  context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
source:
  component: kubelet
  host: aks-default-11069749-vmss000005

message: >-
  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://[ip]:15901/osm-liveness-probe":
  context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
source:
  component: kubelet
  host: aks-default-11069749-vmss000005
```

Deleting and recreating the listener the only error I encounter in the same pod where I found the previous problems is the following (after deleting and recreating the pod):

```
message: 'Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 504'
source:
  component: kubelet
  host: aks-default-11069749-vmss000004
```

I have checked the AzureIngressProhibitedTarget configurations and there don't seem to be any problems and I can't even find a solution to this problem. Has anyone ever faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my version of AGIC was 1.5.1, the first problem was a bug fixed in version 1.5.2 ([read this](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/pull/1390)) the others were a consequence of the first. The resolution was to update AGIC, remove the prohibit-all-targets, and restart the AGIC pod.